# How do you calculate inverse Laplace transform of a fraction

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I need to compute the inverse Laplace transform $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\Big[\frac{3}{(s^2+3)^2}\Big].$$ I already know that the answer is $$ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\Big(\sin(\sqrt{3}t)-\sqrt{3}t\cos(\sqrt{3}t)\Big),$$ but I don't understand how to get it. I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: You can factor $(s^2+3) = (s-i\sqrt{3})(s+i\sqrt{3})$ and then use $$ \frac{1}{(s-a)(s-b)}= \frac{A}{s-a} + \frac{B}{s-b}$$  For its square you can either do something similar or  convolve the non-square result with itself.